# binding.gyp: How to use "copies" section to copy files in multiple location

Tags: c++, electron, node-gyp

I am writing code to load c++ dll from electron. I am using node-gyp. In my binding.gyp file I use "copies" tag to copy dlls to Release folder. However I want to copy few more files to be copied to a different location. I tried hit and trial method to do it but was unsuccessful. Here is how my binding.gyp looks:

```
{
    "targets": [{
            "conditions":[
            ["OS=='win'", {
                "copies":[{ 
                        'destination': './build/Release',
                        'files':[
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/bugtrap/BugTrapU-x64.dll',
                            '../build/bin/msvc/Release64/cloudDrive2Lib.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/ssleay32MD.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoZip64.dll',
                             '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoXML64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoUtil64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNetSSL64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNet64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoJSON64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoFoundation64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoCrypto64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/libeay32MD.dll'
                        ]
                    }]
            }]
        ],
        "target_name": "electronToCppBridge",
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "sources": [
            "src/electronToCppBridge.cc",
        ],
        'include_dirs': [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'libraries': ["../libs/cloudDrive2Lib.lib"],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I was able to achieve this in the following way:

```
{
    "targets": [{
            "conditions":[
            ["OS=='win'", {
                "copies":[
                    { 
                        'destination': './build/Release',
                        'files':[
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/bugtrap/BugTrapU-x64.dll',
                            '../build/bin/msvc/Release64/cloudDrive2Lib.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/ssleay32MD.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoZip64.dll',
                             '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoXML64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoUtil64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNetSSL64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNet64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoJSON64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoFoundation64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoCrypto64.dll',
                            '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/libeay32MD.dll'
                        ]
                    },
                    {                        
                        'destination': './libs',
                        'files':['../build/bin/msvc/Release64/cloudDrive2Lib.lib']
                    }
                ]
            }]
        ],
        "target_name": "electronToCppBridge",
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "sources": [
            "src/electronToCppBridge.cc",
        ],
        'include_dirs': [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'libraries': ["../libs/cloudDrive2Lib.lib"],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: if you want to copy all files in a directory, use double star dot star. In the above example if all files under `../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/` need to be copied, set it to: `../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/**.*`